# Symbolic vector addition

Tags: matrix, symbolic, vector

I'm trying to figure out a nice way to add a mix of symbolic and explicit vectors/matrices without mathematica treating the symbolic vectors as scalars and promoting them to constant arrays.

For example:

In: `Assuming[x \[Element] Matrices[{2, 2}], x + IdentityMatrix[2]]`

Out: `{{1 + x, x}, {x, 1 + x}}`

Of course I could do:

In: `HoldForm[x + IdentityMatrix[2]]`

and not release the hold until I replace everything with its explicit value, but I am hoping that there is a cleaner solution.

Comment: What would be an acceptable output for your first line of code?

Comment: `x + {{1,0},{0,1}}` would be nice. Doing so in a way the was idiomatic/self-documenting would be perfect. Ideally, I don't want people reading my code to have to guess why I used a HoldForm (even without a comment :))

Comment: Would `Inactivate[Plus][x,  IdentityMatrix[2]` do what you want? You can always `Activate` the "frozen" operators down the road when you have values for your variables.

Comment: that's pretty nice, but I'm sure there must be an even more idiomatic way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two possible approaches:

You could inactivate `Plus` as follows:

```
expr = Inactive[Plus][x, IdentityMatrix[2]]
```

[image: formatted output]

```
x = {{1, 1}, {0, 0}};
expr
```

[image: inactive sum]

```
Activate@expr
```

[image: after reactivation]

As you can see, the inactive form will format very similarly to a "normal" plus sign, with a slight color change to indicate its inactive status.

---

Alternatively, you could use an [operator without built-in meaning](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorsWithoutBuiltInMeanings.html) to represent your addition, only replacing it with `Plus` when you are ready to do so.

For instance, one could use CirclePlus, which is also formatted to a nice infix graphical representation reminiscent of a plus sign, for readability:

```
expr = x \[CirclePlus] IdentityMatrix[2]
```

formats to

[image: formatted circleplus]

and similarly `CirclePlus[x, IdentityMatrix[2]]` formats to the same result.

You can then assign values to x whenever you are ready in the course of your calculations:

```
x = {{1, 1}, {0, 0}};
expr
```

[image: no meaning for circle plus]

When you are ready to "reactivate" your operator, replace it with `Plus`:

```
expr /. CirclePlus -> Plus

(* Out: {{2, 1}, {0, 1}} *)
```